# Set content type of document when uploading using client object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, client-object-model, document-info-panel

I am trying to use the Client Object Model in SharePoint to upload a document to a specific library. Right now I have it saving the document but I can't figure out how to specify the content type before uploading.

```
using(var context = new ClientContext("http://mysharepoint/sites/Demo"))
{
    Web currentWeb = context.Web;

    context.Load(currentWeb, web => web.Url);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    List documentList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Public Documents");

    context.Load(documentList, list => list.EntityTypeName);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

   var newFile = new FileCreationInformation()
   {
       Content = ...,
       Overwrite = true,
       Url = "myfile.docx"
   };

   var uploadFile = documentList.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

   // how to set the content type?
   context.Load(uploadFile);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I'm not positive this is the correct way to upload the document so if there is something else wrong please point it out.

Additional question. I am doing this in an Office Add-In project and would like to show the Document Information Panel so they can edit the metadata. Is it possible to do this before uploading the file or would I need to do it after the file is uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example demonstrates how to specify list item properties (Content Type in this case) while uploading the file:

```
var targetList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation()
    {
      Content = fileContent,
      Overwrite = true,
      Url = fileUrl
    };

var uploadFile = targetList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
var listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields; //get associated list item
listItem["ContentTypeId"] = ctId;  //set content type
listItem.Update();

context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying this in Sharepoint 2019 on prem, there are some slight syntax changes.

```
var listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields; //old
var listItem = uploadFile.get_listItemAllFields(); //new

listItem["ContentTypeId"] = ctId;  //old
listItem.set_item("ContentTypeId", ctId); //new

listItem.Update(); //old
listItem.update(); //new (notice the lower case)
```